# Objective-C – Delay UINavigationController pushViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, delay

I use a `UINavigationController` together with a `UITableView` so that when the user touches a cell it will push another view controller on to the screen.

In this view controller that I'm pushing on to the screen I'm loading some HTML in a `UIWebView` so that takes some time before it has finished loading the HTML. I would like to delay the navigation controller (so it waits until the HTML has finished loading) and then pushing the view controller on to the screen. How can I achieve this programatically?

Comment: I think you should rather push the new viewController immediately, and display an indicator that it is still loading, this would make your interface seem more responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would

```
[performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:][1]
```

work for you? Something along the lines of:

```
[navigationController performSelector:@selector(pushNewViewFromTableCell:) withObject:view afterDelay:1.0]
```

But you should be careful about the delayed response that this would produce: the user would touch a row, then, after a delay, the controller would be pushed.

Possibly, you would be better off by displaying a progress indicator in the new view pushed on the navigation controller while it is loading data.

Comment: I've seen apps that have used an activity indicator inside the table view cell while loading the data. Curious how they have coupled the loading of the web view with the table view cell.

Comment: I guess through the UIWebViewDelegate methods that are called to signal when a UIWebView starts loading and when it finishes...

Comment: Ah yes, that is true, just set the UIWebViewDelegate to my table view controller.

Answer (score 1):

You could also implement this and have it "waiting" for the correct delegate function to be invoked:

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

Answer (score 1):

You could not exactly find the download time. So better show the second view with `UIWebView` immediately.

Show the second view with activity indicator started in

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

method.

And in,

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

method, stop and hide the indicator.